# PHP Skip First Line Of CSV If It Contains Specific Header Info

Tags: php, csv

I need to check the first line of a csv file to see if it contains the headers for columns (number, name, amount). If the first line contains these headers then exit the file or add number, name, amount if the first line does not contain this info.

I was trying to check to see if the first column, first row contains a number which would mean no headers.

Heres the code I was using. And thanks again for all your help.

```
$rows = $phones = [];
if (($handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    list($phone, $name, $amount) = $data;
    if(!($data = fgetcsv($handle))) {
return;    //most likely empty file
}
    if(!is_numeric($data[0])) {
        fputcsv($handle, array('number', 'name', 'amount'));
    }

    $phone = str_replace(['(',')','-'], '', $phone);
    $amount = str_replace(['$'], "", $amount);
    $amount = sprintf('$%.2f', $amount);


     // track unique phone numbers here
    if (isset($phones[$phone])) {
        // it's a duplicate so just ignore the entire row
        continue;
    }
    // otherwise it's a new phone number so store it
    $phones[$phone] = true;
    $rows[] = [$phone, $name, $amount];
    // or output directly
    //echo "$phone | $name | $amount";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to choose between:

1. Fixed rule in your loader/exporter to use OR NOT use header for CSV export.
2. Fixed column order; knowing format for `amount` field, you can check if value is valid for any row

To parse "$100.00" to number in PHP:

[NumberFormatter::parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php)

Comment: The csv file will have to have the header row in order for what I'm doing to work. I guess the easiest way will be to do what I was first trying which is checking to see if the first line has a number, which means no header and then either skip or add depending on what is found.